# ckeditor5 Paste with formatting but without images

Tags: paste, ckeditor5

I like to paste but have an option to retain all formatting but have all images stripped. This is particularly useful when users are pasting content from emails to record against a trouble ticket but don't want the image content to be included namely as most of the time the images are in the signature of the emails and in long threads these images don't paste well

I know we can do a ctrl-shift-v paste which does plain text but it loses all the formatting which is a plain than for a user to go through a big paste and format the message

I like this feature either with a new button or a popup asking user if they like to strip out images when an image is detected in a paste